# Javascript function not called when used with IF statement

Tags: javascript

My checkforZeroQuantity function is not getting called if I use it with if. Following is the sample code

```
function myButtonClicked() {
  if (checkforZeroQuantity()) {
    alert("checked");
  }
}

function checkforZeroQuantity() {
  var x = 1;
  if (x == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    retrun true;
  }
}
```

Comment: correct spelling of return in to else condition

Comment: Or simply `return x === 0`

Comment: @elclanrs `!==` according to OP's logic (though the function naming should do the opposite).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, the function doesn't make sense either way, as `x` will always be `1`

Comment: @elclanrs I believe OP is using a constant to simplify a more complex dynamic value source, but I agree it doesn't make much sense to have a function to check if `!== 0`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - yes, it does not make any sense, but I was just curious to know why my function was not getting called.

Comment: Well it would get called if it wasn't for that typo, check your JS console (F12) for errors. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have spelling mistake near as shown below

```
else {
    retrun true; // it should be return
  }
```

correct the spelling and try again.

Answer (score 2):

look here:

```
function checkforZeroQuantity() {
  var x = 1;
  if (x == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There spelling mistake in code, please change 'retrun' to 'return'.

```
else
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a typo in the `else` block.:)

Secondly, it's a good practice to use `===` instead of `==` in `Javascript`